# React Native -- Flatlist Updated but Render Card's state not updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I m working on an app in which I have FlatList and which contains list of cards.
I have survey cards and when user perform any survey I add response of that survey in local DB and updated FlatList. My FlatList got updated but when card got rendered all the local data updated expect the values those I am firstly storing in local state and then show while rendering card.

For example:

**I want to update title of my card on button press**

1. I am adding my card title in local useState because I need that value in future

so, I declared like :

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
```

2. Now I want to update **item.title** on button click:

   ```
    let newArray = [...feedArray];

   const index = newArray.findIndex(object => {
    return object.cardId === item.cardId;
     });

    newArray[index].title = "I am checking issue for survey not updated"

    setFeedArray([...newArray]);
   ```

also, My useEffect is like:

```
 useEffect(() => {

  setTitle(item.title)

  },[]}
```

My **setFeedArray**  list got updated but my card not updated with latest title as I am storing value in local store. If I don't use local state and directly show **item.title** then it got updated but  I want to store my value in **setTitle** and show from there.

What is the issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
const handleButtonClick = () => {
  let newArray = [...feedArray];
  const index = newArray.findIndex(object => {
    return object.cardId === item.cardId;
  });
  newArray[index].title = "I am checking issue for survey not updated";
  setFeedArray([...newArray]);
  setTitle(newArray[index].title);
}
```

It looks like the issue you are facing is related to the way you are updating the title in your FlatList. The problem is that you are using a local state variable (title) to store and display the title of your card, but you are not updating this variable when the title changes.

Comment: Thankyou but sorry not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dependency array for re-rendering.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    
    setTitle(item.title)
  
    },[title])
``
```

Comment: Thankyou @Girraj,  I am using the same card in multiple places like bookmark and feed so when I on it and I am using this code then my current card update.I want to update same card from bookmark too. How to do that?

Comment: If you are using the same component on different screens then you need to use redux for that.

Comment: can Context API will do the same stuff?

Comment: Yes, you can use that too.